# Compiling VTK , VS2010, Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, vtk

I am at a loss here. I am trying to make Visual Studio 2010 compile VTK and be able to use Qt and VTK in the same applications. I am following http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build and I keep getting errors that say LINK.

Specifically I have these errors

LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

and a lot of LNK1181 errors. It seems it can't find vtkmyCommon.lib, vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL-6.3.lib , vtkGUISupportQt-6.3.lib, vtkViewsQt-6.3.lib or vtkmyUnsorted.lib

I am using Qt 4.8.6, VTK 6.0 and VS2010

I don't understand what am I doing wrong or what am I missing. I am new to windows and VS2010.

All the PATHs are set correctly so the problem is not there.

Anyone knows what I could do?

Comment: ***LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'*** This means you are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: ***I am using Qt 4.8.6, VTK 6.0 and VS2010*** Did you compile all of these for 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I am not sure. My windows is 64 bits. I simply downloaded VS2010 and installed it. I dont know VTK's architecture either. I guess I will have to compile Qt in 64 bits (I didn't want to compile) and I am at a loss with all the other libraries

Comment: Here are some links to precompiled binaries for VTK 6.1.0 [VTK VC10_32](http://www.opencascade.com/sites/default/files/private/occt/3rdparty/VTK-6.1.0-vc10-32.zip) and [VTK VC10_64](http://www.opencascade.com/sites/default/files/private/occt/3rdparty/VTK-6.1.0-vc10-64.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install a precompiled Qt 4.8 x64:

   - Simply download and install from [Qt64-NG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/files/qt/x86-64/4.8.7/msvc2010/qt-4.8.7-x64-msvc2010.exe/download)
   - Create an environment variable `QTDIR` point to the installation directory, e.g. `C:\Qt\qt-4.8.7-x64-msvc2010`
   - Add `%QTDIR%\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable

You can test if Qt is correctly installed by opening a `CMD`-prompt and typing `qmake`.

2. Build VTK 6.3 x64:

   - [Download VTK](http://www.vtk.org/files/release/6.3/VTK-6.3.0.zip) and unzip it
   - Create a `build`-directory inside your unzipped VTK-directory
   - Configure with CMake inside the `build`-directory

In command prompt:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64" -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DModule_vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=[INSTALL-DIR] -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=d
cmake --build . --config Release --target install
cmake --build . --config Debug --target install
```